# Most Common Value In Table Multiple Columns Excel

Tags: excel, match, formula, mode

I have about 4,000 rows of text data, across 21 columns. The below formula will return the most common value in a single column:

{=INDEX(E6:E3876,MODE(IF(E6:E3876<>"",MATCH(E6:E3876,E6:E3876,0))))}

However, I need to check all cells in the E6:Y4000 range. Is there a way in Excel to return the most common, non-blank text value in a table that spans multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181494/create-a-custom-function-in-excel) will be much faster than any formula:

```
Function Freq(rng As Range) As String

    Dim cll As Range
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim lngMax As Long
    Dim str As String

    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cll In rng

        If cll.Value <> "" Then
            dic(cll.Value) = dic(cll.Value) + 1
            lngCount = dic(cll.Value)
            If lngCount > lngMax Then
                lngMax = lngCount
                str = cll.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

    On Error GoTo 0

    Freq = str

End Function
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked exactly as intended... Now how would I adjust this function to gather the 2nd most common value, 3rd most common value, etc.?