# Excel: Find MODE of a matrix of strings

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been trying to compute the mode of a matrix of cells (10 x 3) containing words to find the most frequent word. After online research, I could only find this formula: `=INDEX(rng,MODE(MATCH(rng,rng,0)))`, with `rng` meaning the range I want to find the mode of. The problem with the formula is that `rng` can only be single column or single row. If I put my whole range in the formula, I get `#N/A`.

Is there a way to find the mode of the whole matrix? Transforming the matrix into a single column/row is not an option as the matrix is dynamic and rows keep getting added to it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=LET(X,COUNTIF(A1:C5,A1:C5),UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(X=MAX(X),A1:C5,NB),3)))
```

In case of a tie, and you want to show all, then this will spill:

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

If `TOCOL()` (which is in BETA-channel for insiders at time of writing) is not available to you, try:

```
=LET(X,COUNTIF(A1:C5,A1:C5),UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(X=MAX(X),A1:C5,""))&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

This variant will also spill down in case of a tie. Note that using `TEXTJOIN()` got limits but in a 10x3 array of values this will be completely fine.

---

If, however, you are looking for VBA, then I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53734677/9758194) that you could use as a starting point to create your own code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately in my excel version, TOCOL is not recognized as a valid function. I will however try the VBA you linked me.

Comment: What version do you have? @infinitedreamer666

Comment: the standard Microsoft 365 Office pack, you know, from the Microsoft Store. But I read that it is a fairly new feature of April/May 2022. Maybe I need to update it.

Comment: @infinitedreamer666, I edited the answer with another option that does not involve `TOCOL()`.